# ng-disabled not working multiple rows in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In this scenario when I disabling button for status "created", it's disabling the same button for all the row, What i need to disable only for status "Created".

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in ReconciledateLimit">
            <td ng-class="{'changeColorG':cell === 'uploaded', 'changeColorR':cell === 'uploadFailed','changeColorYY':cell === 'created' , 'changeColorY':cell === 'validated','changeColorR':cell === 'validationFailed'}"
                style="word-wrap:break-word;
                font-size: 13px;
                text-align: center"
                ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index">
                {{cell}}
            </td>

            <td style="text-align: center;font-size: 11px">

                <button style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5%;" title="Create File"
                        ng-disabled="'row.FileStatus === created'"

        ng-click="createFile_Request({jobCarrierName : row.Carrier})"><strong>Create</strong></button>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Should that not be `ng-disabled="row.FileStatus === 'created'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes are incorrect:

```
ng-disabled="'row.FileStatus === created'"
```

The string `'row.FileStatus === created'` is always truthy and so all rows are disabled.

You want:

```
ng-disabled="row.FileStatus === 'created'"
```

to actually perform a comparison.

Comment: Thanks it Worked..!

Comment: @SGG Great! When a question has been answered successfully you should accept the answer that you found most helpful. You can find out more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)